# Preact & Formik: Fail to trigger validation on change in a custom Field component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, preact

I have a custom `input` component:

```
function Input({ field }) {
  return <input {...field} />;
}
```

that is used in a Formik's `<Field />` component:

`<Field name="subject" component={Input} />`

And a validation function on the `<Formik />` component:

```
<Formik
     validate={validateField}
     ...
```

The problem is my validation function is not triggered upon every change on the `Input`.

Check out this codesandbox for reproduction:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-elbakyan-y29hh

And strangely, the same code works fine in a React app: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-morning-vij2i

It also works fine in Preact if I just use vanilla `<input />` element. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I fixed it by binding Formik's `onChange` handler to the `onInput`event of my custom input component.

```
function FieldInput({ field: { onChange, ...props } }) {
  return <input onInput={onChange} {...props} />;
}
```

This is due to I suspect React treating `onChange` as `onInput` and somehow Preact/Preact-compat don't play well with that?

Comment: Interesting! Preact doesn't implement a custom wrapper over native DOM events like React does, so maybe you should file this as a bug to the preact team.

Comment: @zackkrida it's not a bug but a design decision, as written in the docs: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/differences-to-react#use-oninput-instead-of-onchange

It's possible to use preact/compat to patch this onInput/onChange React anomaly.